# Can I reference the service name docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker-compose.yaml, is there a way to reference the service name (web, database), so that in the code below, the volumes would be created as  `/store/web`  for web and  `/store/database` for database ?

```
---
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    volumes:
    - /store/${reference_service_name_above}

  database:
    volumes:
    - /store/${reference_service_name_above}
```

Answer (score 2):

The docker-compose documentation does not provide for that.

You might want to use the common pattern of creating volumes within your stack file for use in containers.

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - web-logs:/var/log/web

volumes:
  web-logs:
    external: true
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/swarm/

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use the variable `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name

> Sets the project name. This value is prepended along with the service name to the container on start up. For example, if your project name is `myapp` and it includes two services `db` and `web`, then Compose starts containers named `myapp_db_1` and `myapp_web_1` respectively.

Answer (score -3):

My answer is to extract `docker-compose images`.

```
docker-compose images | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $2}' | sed s/.*_//
```

This command change this return

```
$ docker-compose images
    Container           Repository       Tag       Image Id      Size 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
mytool_web_1   mytool_web   latest   e51243243b8c   782 MB
```

to this;

```
web
```

NOTE: I didn't test it on a yml which has multiple services.